# Stream mp3 using Java technology

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, distributed, smartgwt

**I need to buid distributed computing system that use java technology to access mp3 files stored in seperate servers.

In the user interface layer users can play audio files.
In the information processing layer application client implementing with database servers.(where audio and user data stored) 
In the information processing I need to be able to manage audio files.
My questions are,

1. What is the best framework to get started?
2. Am I able to use different technologies like SmartGWT, SmartGWT EE, mySQL, JSF together?
3. What is the best mp3 player that work with java?**

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming your client is a browser)

The easiest way:

1. On the client side use a Flash player that plays mp3 downloaded via HTTP. You can write your own or pick one on the web (there are plenty available): [example](http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/).
2. Serve your mp3 files as static files via a web server, or write Java Servlet that serves this files. In second case you could have more control and implement [progressive HTTP download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download).

Comment: Peter, My browser will do "1" already (i.e. given an blah.mp3 link, it will play it).  I'm trying to implement a simple "2".  Do you know of any Java samples that do the progressive HTTP download?

Answer (score 0):

I'll only answer question about streaming:

There's the [locality-icecast](http://code.google.com/p/locality-icecast/) project that implements an icecast streaming server in java, but it was abandoned, so you can pick up the development. You can also take a look at [JRoar](http://www.jcraft.com/jroar/), it's an icecast server for ogg, but it's generally same thing and you can get some ideas from it too.

This way any player that supports shoutcast/icecast protocol will work with your server.

If you want to write your own player, you can decode mp3 using [JavaLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) library.